# how to perform summation based on condition in datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable with 5 line items in which two 2 line items have same material code. Based on material code i have to sum quantity,tax etc., of that two line items and display it as single line item.
 Below is my SQl query to fil the datatable.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT RQ.RQ_MTL_CODE,MM.MM_SHRT_DESC,RQ.RQ_TRANTYPE,RQ.RQ_TRANQTY,RQ.RQ_RATE,RQ.RQ_GROSS,RQ.RQ_DISCOUNT,RQ.RQ_TOT_TAX_VAL,RQ.RQ_NETT,RQ.RQ_MRP FROM REQUEST_FILE AS RQ ,MATL_MASTER AS MM where RQ.RQ_MTL_CODE = MM.MM_CODE and rq.rq_mrp=mm.mm_mrp and RQ.RQ_CO_CODE='" + Session["sapno"] + "' AND RQ.RQ_REFERENCE_NO ='" + refno + "' AND RQ.RQ_STATUS='" + status1 + "' and rq.rq_cantrg='Y' and rq.rq_download='Y' ", con);
               DataTable dt_new = new DataTable(); da.Fill(dt_new);
```

[image: image enclosed is my data in datatable]

i need to sum last two line items and display it as single record.
Kindly do the needful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Compute method in datatable :

```
dt.Compute("Sum(value)","baseCode = 55")
```

> parameter1 : aggregate function
>   parameter2 : condition

Edit:

you should follow these steps :

1-  create a newRow from your databale and do your summation and fill it

2- detach thouse rows you want

3- attach the new row to your datatable

Comment: Thank for your reply Amir.. I didnt think so this wil solve my problem.